# Sed: Replace T 2016-12-30T09:42:14 from ISO date

Tags: text-processing, sed

How to replace T from `2016-12-30T09:42:14` date format?

Expected format: `2016-12-30 09:42:14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 2016-12-30T09:42:14 \
| sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\)T\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)/\1 \2/'
```

- `[0-9]` matches any digit
- `\{4\}` means the preceding thing should appear exactly 4 times (shorter than `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`)
- `\(...\)` creates a capture group, the capture groups can be refered to by their number (`\1`, `\2` etc.)

Comment: this sed command is replacing only first occurrence of match in single line. How to replace all such matched pattern within every line of file?

Comment: Add `g` after the last `/`.

Answer (score 0):

`echo 2016-12-30T09:42:14  | sed -re 's/(-[0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:)/\1 \2/g'`

`-r` means that you do not need the `\`'s -> easier to read
`-<two digits>T<two digits>:` is unlikely to give false matches

Result: A lot shorter and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your input text is, but if you are certain your format looks like you shown, the simplest code would be

```
echo "2016-12-30T09:42:14" | sed -e 's/T/ /g'
```